# Can I implement and share implementations of papers

Tags: publications

Can I implement and share implementations of papers on say, GitHub? Can I licence those implementations such that if people are using my implementations they have to cite?

Comment: Do you mean the papers of other people? What field are you asking about? What sort of "implementations"?

Comment: Can you describe more clearly exactly that you want to achieve? To me it unclear what kind of "*implementations of papers*" you are referring to.

Comment: Presuming this is about implementing an approach in code, yes you can. One question might be why would somebody else use your implementation? The more barriers to using it the less likely somebody will be to use it.

Comment: Hello there. I am studying on MRI. Generally, the implementations I am talkin about are reconstruction algorithms from other people's papers. I am implementing them on MATLAB generally and I want to share those implementations.

Comment: MRI = Magnetic Resonance Imaging or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is magnetic resonance imaging

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement them. Technically, you can attach any license you like, as long as it passes legal muster. In practice you'll find it very difficult to enforce a "you must cite this" license, but you can try.

Comment: Well, getting cited is not important at all. However, I am investing lots of time to implement those algorithms and I want to at least create a repository that can act as a portfolio for my resume. What I really want is to make people understand and beleive that I am actually implementing those papers :D

Comment: If the repository is in your name, and you have a commit history, I'm sure no one is going to doubt you.